# Setting up config files in AWS OpsWorks/Chef for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I suppose I should start with the caveat that I'm very new to OpsWorks and Chef.  I'm trying to setup a RoR app using the provided "Rails App Server" layer. My application depends on a config.yml file being present in the config/ directory, so I created a really simple recipe that is supposed to create that file for me:

```
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|

  template "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/shared/config/config.yml" do
    source "config.yml.erb"
    cookbook 'current_client_spin'
    mode "0660"
    group deploy[:group]
    owner deploy[:user]

    notifies :run, "execute[restart Rails app #{application}]"

    only_if do
      File.directory?("#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/shared/config/")
    end
  end

end
```

My cookbook structure includes a /templates/default/ directory which contains the correct .erb files.

I added this recipe to the "Deploy" cycle, and through judicious use of logging statements, I can see that the recipe is getting invoked, but the file isn't being created. I investigated a bit further, and it appears that at the point where my recipe is being invoked, the `deploy[:deploy_to]/shared/config` directory doesn't exist. This is despite the fact that the default Rails recipe apparently places some other files there -- so I'm extremely confused.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out this was a bit of a "well duh" moment. I was putting my recipe in the wrong "slot". I needed them in the "Setup" slot, not "Deploy" or "Configure". Hopefully if anyone else finds themselves with this kind of head-scratcher, this will help them out.

Comment: I tried this. But "deploy[:deploy_to]/shared/config" wasn't being created even in the setup lifecycle. Could you please help, Steve?